# How to put an icon instead of numbers in slider label. Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

<mat-slider [thumbLabel]="true" color="primary">

I have a label and it is displaying numbers, but i need to change to custom icon. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI80z.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Bch.png)
On the photos u can see how it is now and how it should be.

Using Angular Material components and Angular 13

Was trying to work directly with html code of angular component, but it didnt give any result. Also was reading some info about displayWith and displayLabelAs, but didnt found any documentation about this

Answer (score 0):

override the slider indicator style like this.

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-slider .mdc-slider__value-indicator {
      background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/pause.png)!important;
    }
```

this will add the image as a background.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/wslqqu?file=src%2Fexample%2Fslider-configurable-example.css)